# finding the order of the polynomials in a polynomial groups under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is:   if  G:= Group of polynomials under addition with elements from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$
$f(x)=7x^2+5^x+4$ and $g(x)=4x^2+8^x+6$  ,$f(x)+g(x)=x^2+3x$
what is the order of $f(x)$,$g(x)$,$f(x)+g(x)$
i find that the answers are $10$,$5$ and $10$ . Am i correct??
(i noticed that zero polynomial is the identity here)
then if $h(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0$ belongs to $G$ what is the order of it? given that

$gcd(a_1,a_2,,,a_n)=1$,

$gcd(a_1,a_2,,,,a_n)=2$,

$gcd(a_1,a_2,,,a_n)=5$,

$gcd(a_1,a_2,,,a_n)=10$

Here i do not understand how to proceeded ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: can some one help me in the second part of the problem? i think i have solved the first part since you  have to add the f(x) at least  10 times then you get the zero polynomial(the identity in this case)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution to 2nd part in the attached file[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXE4i.jpg)]

Comment: You can attach two images in a single answer too .

Answer (score -1):

Find the solution in the attached picture

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRtrp.jpg]